# How to perform math calculations in Active Record Querying in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm building an application and I'm finding it necessary to perform some simple math calculations in my query.  Essentially, I've got a database with daily values from the S&P 500, and I need to get a listing of days depending on the criteria entered.

The user inputs both a day range, and a % range.  For instance, if the date range is Jan 1/2013 - Apr 1/2013 and the % range is -1% - 1%, it should return a list of all S%P 500 daily values between the dates where difference between the opening and closing values are in the % range.

The problem is that I don't actually have a column for %; I only have a column for opening/closing values.  It is simple enough to calculate the % given only the opening and closing values (close-open)/open*100.  But I'm not sure how to do this within the query.

Right now the query is successfully searching within the date range.  My query is:

```
@cases = Close.find(:all, conditions:["date between ? and ?",
    @f_start, @f_end])
```

But how can I  get it to check if the current row's (close-open)/open*100 value is between the two % range values?

Alternatively, if this is not possible or in bad practice, where should I be handling this?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the open/close range yourself in Ruby/Rails and pass it on the same way you do with the date range. Something like:

```
percent = @f_percent / 100.0 # 5% => 0.05
low = @f_close * (1.0 - percent)
high = @f_close * (1.0 + percent)
Close.where 'date between ? and ? AND close between ? and ?', \
  @f_start, @f_end, low, high
```